# Аналог сигналов Django в Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, django

Ребят, вот есть в Django такое понятие как сигналы, а есть ли в Zend Framework что-то похожее?

Comment: Ушел с django на zend? :)

Comment: Не то чтобы ушел, просто пишу и на том и на том :) Вот и озадачился... Думаю пусть вопросик еще повисит денек, потом закрою, если ответов не будет.

Comment: Не нужно закрывать вопросы, не имеющие ответов. Когда-нибудь они, возможно, появятся.

Comment: @neoascetic, переоткрыл вопрос. Если есть ответ, велкам.

Answer (score 1):

Разве это не [EventManager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html)? Или [Zend_EventManager_EventManager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ru/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html) для старого ZF.